# Java: In an array of objects, how can we extract objects of a specified subclass

Tags: java, arrays, object, subclass

This was my attempt:

```
String type;
kb.nextLine();
type=kb.nextLine(); 
for (PersonalInformation  individual : arr) {
    if(individual != null && type.equals("Full-Time Faculty") ) {   
       if(individual instanceof FullTimeFaculty){ 
          individual.showInfo();
        } 
     }
}
```

In the output for this case, it only shows the info of the first object of the subclass in the array rather than all of them.

Comment: What is this `type` variable?

Comment: Don't use tabs for indentations but rather spaces in your posted code as the site's formatting software does not handle tabs well. I tried to improve your questions formatting for you, but in the future we ask that you do this yourself. Edit: also you're crowding too much code on each line. Give each line of code it's own line.

Comment: As for your question, the [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might be useful here.

Comment: I added the the type variable creation

Comment: Also as an aside, better to avoid using Strings for type information. Perhaps a class or an enum would work better for this.

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem logical from the naming you chose. FullTimeFaculty has PersonalInformation (not "is-a"). Besides, without a complete inheritance tree is very difficult to determine. How are these classes related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough information but check this cases

1. `arr` constains just one element
2. `individual instanceof FullTimeFaculty` is false
3. `individual` is null

Try to add `else` Blocks to understand the problem:

```
for (PersonalInformation  individual : arr) {
    if(individual != null && "Full-Time Faculty".equals(type) ) { // constant left : variable right !  
        if(individual instanceof FullTimeFaculty){ 
            individual.showInfo();
        } else {
            System.err.println("not FullTimeFaculty");
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("null or not Full-Time Faculty");
    }
}
```